# Django Form, Calculating a new value from the form and assign it to the model

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm pretty new with Django and the whole web-developing concept. I've only taken Java and C++ , but I got a job working as a web-developer at my university. I'm currently trying to implement a form - (http://albedo.csrcdev.com/pages/submit). In my models, I have one more field that doesn't show up on my form, which is called Albedo. Albedo is supposed to be calculated by sum( outgoing1, outgoing2, outgoing3 ) / sum( incoming1, incoming2, incoming3 ). So my question is, how and where do I take those variables from the database, and assign the new calculated value to Albedo.

My co-worker told me to use ModelForm for my form, and try doing it in views.py but now I'm sitting here stuck and clueless and he just left for vacation! :(

Thanks in advance,

David

views.py

```
@login_requried
def submit( request ):
if request.method =='POST':
     form = DataEntryForm( request.POST )
     model = DataEntry( )
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/map/rebuild/')                                            


else:                                                                                           
    form = DataEntryForm( )                                                                        

return render_to_response(
      'pages/submit.html', { 'form': form },
      context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

Comment: can you post some of your views.py code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
form = DataEntryForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.albedo = do_calc(instance.whatever0, instance.whatever1)
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/map/rebuild/')
```

Note that you don't need to instantiate `model = DataEntry()` manually - if `DataEntryForm` is a `ModelForm` subclass, it'll create the model when you call `.save()`.

It would probably be a good idea to encapsulate the calculation in a `DataEntry.update_albedo()` method or something. You would call that before `instance.save()` instead doing the calculation in the view itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's simple and gets the job done, which is probably the best way.

Answer (score 3):

I would assign this value from the `save` method of the `ModelForm`.

Assuming that `albedo` is a field name in your model, too:

```
Class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('albedo')

    def calculate_albedo(outgoing1, outgoing2, outgoing3, incoming1,
                                            incoming2, incoming3):
        return sum([outgoing1, outgoing2, outgoing3]) / sum([incoming1, 
                       incoming2, incoming3])

    def save(self, commit=True):
        form_data = self.cleaned_data
        self.instance.someval1 = form_data['someval1']
        self.instance.someval2 = form_data['someval2']
        self.instance.someval3 = form_data['someval3']
        self.instance.albedo = self.calculate_albedo(
                    form_data['outoing1'], form_data['outoing2'], 
                    form_data['outoing3'], form_data['incoming1'], 
                    form_data['incoming2'], form_data['incoming3'])
        return super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit)
```

Also, if `Albedo` is not a class name you should use lowercase. It's [Pythonic convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to update field in [presave signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save). With this approach:

- Your Albedo field is updated before save model.
- Remember you can do a save no commit `save(commit=False)`. This will update your field without commit changes to database.

I post a sample taked from [django signals doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.Albedo = sender.outgoing1 + ...
```